# Macro to run in sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macros like alpha1, alpha2, alpha3 etc and created onother macro to call these in sequence but now my problem is if alpha2 is getting failed then alpha3 is not executing, please someone help me on this.

```
Sub Dashboard()    
    Call sum_borders
    call alpha1
    call alpha2
    call alpha3
    Call sum_borders
    MsgBox ("WH-Detailed report has been created")
End Sub
```

if alpha1 is executed or failed then goto alpha2 and if alpha2 is executed or failed then goto alpha3 and so on.

Comment: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Thanks PEH but i am using error handler in each of this macro but it is not running in sequence, if one of these macro fails other is not executing.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. Please include the code of your other procedures, so we can see what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you're fine with the codes returning an error/failing, then a solution for your problem is that you could include `on error resume next`, in each of your individual codes (Alpha1, alpha2, alpha3) before the line which triggers the fail.

But this is not recommended, you should be aware of the reason which is resulting error. Please go through the link that @peh shared.